# how to automount a virtualbox shared folder on a guest OS with specific options?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, shared-folders

virtualbox by default mounts shared folders as user root, group vboxsf, and 770 permissions on everything.

I would like to mount with specific options, namely

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf myshare /media/sf_myshare/ -o rw,uid=501,gid=20
```

I can manually unmount the automounted share and run the above command, but I'd like these options applied automatically.   I can't find any file in /etc/ that controls the vbox share mount settings

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be controlled by the `vbsvcAutoMountWorker` as defined by `VBoxServiceAutoMount.cpp`, and the mount log indicates that the `vbsvcAutoMountSharedFolder` function is involved, which is called by something that [manually sets the group to `vboxsf`](https://www.virtualbox.org/browser/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Additions/common/VBoxService/VBoxServiceAutoMount.cpp#L506). Changing this appears to require changing the code and recompiling, or to request a feature that the options be settable via a "guestproperty" or "extradata" or some other means...